# Hide list-style image for one specific list item

Tags: asp.net, html-lists

I am having an unordered list like:

```
<ul style="list-style: square url(Images/rssIconSmall.png)">
                    <li><h3>All Items</h3></li>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
```

Since I am giving "list-style" as image it appears for all the list items. But I do not want to display the image for the first item. I mean for "All Items" the image should not be displayed. Is it possible?Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add style="list-style:none outside none;" on the element you don't want to have a bullet. Or customize it however you want.

Regards, Alin

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS `:first-child` selector.

```
ul li:first-child {
 display: none;
}
```

PS. Some browsers (such as IE) may not work well with that selector: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

or better yet,

```
/* CSS */
ul li.first {
 display: none;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<ul style="list-style: square url(Images/rssIconSmall.png)">
                    <li class="first"><h3>All Items</h3></li>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
```